# Saving memory space in Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I'm working with large Numpy arrays and I have been running into some memory issues when integrating the arrays and etc. One option to deal with this is to do the operations in small increments, which I'm already working on. However, because of the nature of my data, large chunks of my arrays are nonexistent.

For example, if I have an array such as

```
x = np.full((100,100,100), np.nan)
```

after I populate it, often large chunks (for example `x[90:,:,80:]`) of it simply don't exist in my dataset, which I flag by leaving the value as NaN, so when I plot and do other things with it, it just gets ignored like it doesn't exist. So far so good.

However, I was wondering if there was a way that I could use this to my advantage, if by instead of leaving the nonexistent spaces as `np.nan`, which use up memory, I just flag them as something that doesn't use up space. Something like

```
x[90:,:,80:,:] = np.nothing
```

or something like that. I realize that something like the above couldn't work because the space has to be marked on the disk as occupied by the array, but I'm still thinking that some method should exist.

Things I've looked at are sparse matrices (but they only work for 2-D arrays), masked arrays (which don't help) and things like `np.empty` (which also didn't help).

*EDIT*

The nonexistent parts are always well-defined blocks/chunks. They're never randomly spaced throughout the array.

Comment: So, sparse matrices didn't help?

Comment: @Divakar I couldn't try because I found that it only supports 2-D matrices (I only know the scipy package). I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: scipy sparse matrices are 2d, and assume the empty spaces are 0.  They were originally designed for large linear algebra problems.

Comment: Roughly what's the ratio of these `nan` chunks to the whole array?  Are they always well defined blocks (with slices)?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, they're always well-defined blocks (I'll add that to the question). And the ratio really depends. They can be from 10% to 70% of the array sometimes.